# Drop constraints not knowing its name

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-scripts

My problem.
I have a database and it is a big one, I want to remove a specific constraint between to table and i wanna do it with a migration scripts written in Visual Studio. I have it for development purposes running locally on my pc but it also runs on a staging server.
I could use the name of the constraint locally and it would work, but on the staging server the name is different. So thats why I want to do without knowing its name.

I've been reading a lot post here on stackoverflow regarding same issue but none of them works for me.

I've build a small databaseto try different code on before i try it on the big DB.

It looks like this:

[image: The small DB]

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Genres')

SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Genres')
```

And this

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @SQL += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + ';' 
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE_DESC LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) = 'Albums';

EXECUTE @SQL
```

In both cases it finds the constraint tries to drop it, but is still there.
It even prints out the name of the constraint i want to remove.

[image]

Comment: Sidenote, Sql isnet my string side :)

Comment: append schema name to at constrain name ..